# Strange route problem in laravel 6 as adding path by own

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-6

i have created one view file to show course list by category id.

**web.php**

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/category/{id?}', 'UserController@category');
```

But my category page is not showing the logo image. i have header file which i have included in category page as header. as i have inspected it shows the logo image source as
`/category/public/asset......` but it suppose to be started from `public/asset.......`

if i do not write `/{id?}` in route with `category`, it show everything properly.

**siteHeader.blade.php**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/')}}">
<img src="public/assets/images/logo.png"  width="280"  height="75" alt=""/>
```

**category.blade.php**
@include('siteHeader')

**UserController.php**

```
    public function category(request $request,$id)
{
    
        $course = DB::table('course')
        ->select('course.*')
        ->where('course.slug', '=' , $id)
        ->orderBy('course.id', 'DESC');
 

        $course = $course->paginate(20);

        return view('category')->with(compact('course'));
   
}
```

Comment: Look at the source for your page when the CSS isn't working, and check your Network tab. Your CSS and images really need to have a full path starting from /, otherwise it will be relative to your current URL path

Comment: Can you please show the code? Where are you storing the logos?

Comment: "_but it suppose to be started from public/asset_" The `public/` folder should not appear in any urls, it should be the "document root" of your project/server/vhost

Comment: siteHeader.balde.php <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url('/')}}"> <img src="public/assets/images/logo.png" width="280" height="75" alt=""/> </a>                                                      Category.blade.php <!-- header --> @include('siteHeader') <!-- //header -->                      i have this @include('siteHeader') in every page which show logo properly. but in category/id route shows img inspect path as category/public/asset instead of public/asset...... only

Comment: UserController.php
    public function category(request $request,$id)
    {
        
            $course = DB::table('course')
            ->select('course.*')
            ->where('course.slug', '=' , $id)
            ->orderBy('course.id', 'DESC');
     

            $course = $course->paginate(20);

            return view('category')->with(compact('course'));
       
    }

Comment: As I mentioned, all images, css, and js assets should start with a `/`, or else it will look relative to your URL path instead of starting from the root. `src="/public/assets/images/logo.png"`

Comment: but i have mentioned this href="{{url('/')}}"> already